# Keep text in clipboard when no longer highlighted

Tags: gnome, clipboard

When I select text (Centos8, Gnome) I can middle click to paste it, but only as long as the original text is still highlighted. The clipboard seems to clear out once the highlighting is removed (like if I click in a spot to make space for the paste). I find this annoying since I'm used to the last selection staying in the clipboard until something new is highlighted.  Is there a setting to change this behavior?